# Protecting/Crypting an external storage

Tags: encryption, passwords, disk-encryption, usb-drive, protection

We have an camera with sd card in which it records. AFAIK its software, recording parts etc., cannot be stepped in. We wish a mechanism/methodology that whenever it is plugged into usb socket of a computer(i.e. via sd card reader), data which is within it cannot be read without asking password. Is there any mechanism/methodology/way to do the intention or similar??

Comment: Assuming that the camera itself does not support writing to some encrypted storage (most cameras don't) and you cannot change the software as you've said, then there is no way to magically make the camera write to encrypted storage. And there is also no way that an SD card gets magically encrypted just because you took the SD card out of the camera and into the computer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That should be an answer, not a comment...

Comment: Interesting question. There might be a product opportunity here. Something like a hardware security module with SD card attachment. Unplug the module and it forgets the key until you enter a pin or something. I haven't heard of anything like this existing, though.

Comment: Does the camera support streaming to a server? It would probably be easier to set up a centralized recording station with encrypted disks than it would be to work from the camera alone. Cost of a central recorder would diminish the more cameras you operate.